# PHP: How to popualate list from sqlite table

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to populate my Php form list from sqlite table. Following is the code:

```
<?php
$db =  new PDO("sqlite:c:/sqlite/test.db");  
$smt = $db->prepare('select person_name From persons');
$smt->execute();
$data = $smt->fetchAll();   ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>formDemo.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form Demo</h1>
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>choose Profile Collection Id and Call Type  </legend>
       <p>
         <label>Profile_Collection_Id 1</label>
         <select id = "myList">
           <?php 
    foreach ($data as $row)?>
            < option><?php  $row["person_name"]?></option>
      endforeach ?>
         </select>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I am not getting where i am going wrong as list is empty when I run this code. Can someone help.

Comment: After this line: `$data = $smt->fetchAll(); ?>` can you do a `<?php var_dump($data); ?>` and include the results in your answer as well?  We need to confirm `$data` is not empty and you are successfully retrieving your query results from the database.

Comment: I did it, out put ids : `array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(4) "John" [0]=> string(4) "John" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(4) "Jian" [0]=> string(4) "Jian" } [2]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(3) "Tom" [0]=> string(3) "Tom" } [3]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(5) "Jerry" [0]=> string(5) "Jerry" } [4]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(5) "Torry" [0]=> string(5) "Torry" } [5]=> array(2) { ["Person_Name"]=> string(3) "nee" [0]=> string(3) "nee" } }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your query is returning results:

```
<select id="myList">
    <?php 
        foreach ($data as $row){
            echo '<option value="' . $row['Person_Name'] . '">' . $row['Person_Name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but the list is still empty :-(

Comment: `$row['Person_Name']` is case sensitive, it should work now based on what you put in your above comment showing the results of `$data`

Answer (score 0):

echo is missing

```
<?php 
    foreach ($data as $row)?>
        < option><?php echo $row["person_name"]?></option>
    endforeach 
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately its not making any difference. I was not now getting any warning for it, even after the change the page is displaying list as before (without data)

Comment: before execute the loop try to print_r($data);  is there any data on this array?

Comment: No its not printing anything even if i print a message its not printing. I am new to programming, so not sure where in the form this  will get printed.

Comment: <?php  print_r($data);  ?>  put this line after <h1>Form Demo</h1>